# How to set a parameter while using Expression<Func<T>>

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

I have written the following code to handle mapping parameters from my database to my data types (trust me I wish I could use a std. ORM but that isn't doable for so many reasons)

```
public void LoadDatabaseValue<T>(DataTable partData, string identifier, string mappingName, Expression<Func<T>> mappingProperty)
    {
        var partAttributeValue = mappingProperty.Name;
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)mappingProperty.Body;
        var prop = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
        try
        {
            var selectedRow = partData.Select($"partattributename = '{mappingName}'");
            var selectedValue = selectedRow[0]["PartAttributeValue"];

            var typedOutput = (T)Convert.ChangeType(selectedValue, typeof(T));

            prop.SetValue(memberExpression.Expression, typedOutput, null);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _databaseImportError = true;
            // code to log this error
    }
```

When I try to run this I get the following exception

```
{System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj,   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)   }
```

When I debug it my typedOutput lines up with my property type, so I am not sure why it is throwing this exception.

I am calling it with for example

```
LoadDatabaseValue(partData, identifier, "Offset", () => Offset);
```

Comment: You are passing a `Func` but expecting it to be `Expression<Func<>>`. Change either of them to same type.

Comment: @Venky He's passing in an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your current method design, you need a way to somehow evaluate the `memberExpression.Expression` in order to be able to call `SetValue` method.

So change the line

```
prop.SetValue(memberExpression.Expression, typedOutput, null);
```

to

```
prop.SetValue(Evaluate(memberExpression.Expression), typedOutput, null);
```

and then use one of the following implementations:

(A) This will be sufficient if you use only property accessors:

```
static object Evaluate(Expression e)
{
    if (e == null) return null;
    var me = e as MemberExpression;
    if (me != null)
        return ((PropertyInfo)me.Member).GetValue(Evaluate(me.Expression), null);
    return ((ConstantExpression)e).Value;
}
```

(B) This one is more universal, but slower:

```
static object Evaluate(Expression e)
{
    if (e == null) return null;
    return Expression.Lambda(e).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `SetValue` must be an object containing the property whose value you want to set.

```
var obj = new TEntity();
prop.SetValue(obj, typedOutput); // From .NET 4.5 there is an overload with just 2 parameters
```

Now `obj.Offset` should have the desired value.

So there are two types involved: The type of the object containing the property and the type of the property itself (e.g. `int`, `string` etc.).

Therefore your expression should be like this:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> mappingProperty
```

where `TEntity` is the type of the object and `object` is the yet unknown type of a property of this object. Unless you know the type of the property in advance, in which case you would have

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> mappingProperty
```

You would call it like this:

```
LoadDatabaseValue(partData, identifier, "Offset", x => x.Offset);
```

You must change the type like this (unless the `selectedValue` is already of the correct type):

```
object typedOutput = Convert.ChangeType(selectedValue, prop.PropertyType);
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this but the signature LoadDatabaseValue(partData, identifier, "Offset", x => x.Offset); wouldn't compile.  What is the benefit of this method over the other solution presented?

Comment: The type `TEntity` must have an `Offset` property of course. You are trying to set the value of `memberExpression.Expression`. But this expression contains only meta information on the real expression and does not represent the real object itself. I do not understand fully what you are trying to do, but I would declare the method like this: `public void LoadDatabaseValue<TEntity>(DataTable partData, TEntity entity, string mappingName, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> mappingProperty)` and call `prop.SetValue(entity, typedOutput);` in order to fill one property of the entity object.

Comment: And also `typedOutput` must contain a value of the right type, but can itself be typed as `object`, since the parameter type in `SetValue` is `object` anyway.

Comment: What about what I am doing do you not fully understand?

Comment: Yes, because `prop.SetValue(memberExpression.Expression, ...);` makes no sense to me. You must set the value of a real object. By this I mean that you must have a class representing the table columns as properties. If you have a table "Customer" you must have a class `Customer`. If the table has a column "FirstName" then the class must have a property `FirstName`. This is how O/R-mappers work. Or am I wrong? A customer is just an example of what I call "entity". You could also call it "model" or "business object".